# enviar un formulario por correo utilizando Muse

Tags: php, html5

tengo hecho un formulario que al enviar al correo me muestra el siguiente error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca les comparto el codigo del formulario

```
<form class="form-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu12198" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="localhost/new_arreglosya/scripts/form-u12198.php">
                    <!-- none box -->
                    <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu12223" data-required="true">
                        <!-- none box -->
                        <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u12224-4" for="widgetu12223_input">
                            <!-- content -->
                            <span class="actAsPara">Nombre</span>
                        </label>
                        <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u12225-4"><!-- content -->
                            <input class="wrapped-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu12223_input" name="custom_U12223" tabindex="1"/>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu12207" data-required="true" data-type="email">
                        <!-- none box -->
                        <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u12210-5" for="widgetu12207_input">
                            <!-- content -->
                            <span class="actAsPara">&nbsp;¿Donde se realizará el trabajo?</span>
                            <span class="actAsPara" id="u12210-3">&nbsp;</span>
                        </label>
                        <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u12209-4"><!-- content -->
                            <input class="wrapped-input" type="email" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu12207_input" name="Email" tabindex="2"/>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u12220-4">
                        <!-- content -->
                        <p>Submitting Form...</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u12221-4">
                        <!-- content -->
                        <p>The server encountered an error.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u12211-4">
                        <!-- content -->
                        <p>Form received.</p>
                    </div>
                    <button class="submit-btn NoWrap clearfix grpelem" id="u12222-4" type="submit" value="&nbsp;enviar" tabindex="5">
                        <!-- content -->
                        <div style="margin-top:-15px;height:15px;">
                            <p>&nbsp;enviar</p>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                    <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu12199" data-required="true">
                        <!-- none box -->
                        <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u12202-4" for="widgetu12199_input">
                            <!-- content --><span class="actAsPara">Celular</span>
                        </label>
                        <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u12201-4"><!-- content --><input class="wrapped-input" type="tel" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu12199_input" name="custom_U12199" tabindex="3"/><label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt" id="widgetu12199_prompt" for="widgetu12199_input"><span class="actAsPara">Introducir Celular</span></label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu12212" data-required="true">
                        <!-- none box -->
                        <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u12215-4" for="widgetu12212_input">
                            <!-- content --><span class="actAsPara">Mail:</span></label>
                        <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u12214-4"><!-- content --><input class="wrapped-input" type="tel" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu12212_input" name="custom_U12212" tabindex="4"/><label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt" id="widgetu12212_prompt" for="widgetu12212_input"><span class="actAsPara">Introducir mail</span></label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

y aca el metodo que recibe los datos

```
require_once('form_process.php');
$form = array(
    'subject' => 'Envío de Pintura, Interiores, Blanco, Con Material',
    'heading' => 'Envío de nuevo formulario',
    'success_redirect' => '',   
    'resources' => array(
        'checkbox_checked'                      => 'Marcada',
        'checkbox_unchecked'                    => 'No marcada',
        'submitted_from'                        => 'Formulario enviado desde el sitio web: %s',
        'submitted_by'                          => 'Dirección IP del visitante: %s',
        'too_many_submissions'                  => 'Se han realizado recientemente demasiados envíos a través de esta IP',
        'failed_to_send_email'                  => 'Error al enviar el correo electrónico',
        'invalid_reCAPTCHA_private_key'         => 'Clave privada de reCAPTCHA no válida.',
        'invalid_reCAPTCHA2_private_key'        => 'Clave privada de reCAPTCHA 2.0 no válida.',
        'invalid_reCAPTCHA2_server_response'    => 'Respuesta de servidor de reCAPTCHA 2.0 no válida.',
        'invalid_field_type'                    => 'Tipo de campo desconocido: %s.',
        'invalid_form_config'                   => 'El campo \'%s\' contiene una configuración no válida.',
        'unknown_method'                        => 'Método de solicitud de servidor desconocido'
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'from' => 'arreglosya1@gmail.com',
        'to' => 'angelgutierrez1983@gmail.com'
    ),
    'fields' => array(
        'custom_U12223' => array(
            'order' => 1,
            'type' => 'string',
            'label' => 'Nombre',
            'required' => true,
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'El campo \'Nombre\' es obligatorio.'
            )
        ),
        'Email' => array(
            'order' => 2,
            'type' => 'email',
            'label' => ' ¿Donde se realizará el trabajo?',
            'required' => true,
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'El campo \' ¿Donde se realizará el trabajo?\' es obligatorio.',
                'format' => 'El campo \' ¿Donde se realizará el trabajo?\' contiene un correo electrónico no válido.'
            )
        ),
        'custom_U12199' => array(
            'order' => 3,
            'type' => 'string',
            'label' => 'Celular',
            'required' => true,
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'El campo \'Celular\' es obligatorio.'
            )
        ),
        'custom_U12212' => array(
            'order' => 4,
            'type' => 'string',
            'label' => 'Mail',
            'required' => true,
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'El campo \'Mail\' es obligatorio.'
            )
        )
    )
);

process_form($form);
```

esta realizo en php y html sin ningun tipo de framewor ni configuracion especial, solo Muse

Comment: estas ejecutando tu desarrollo en local o en que tipo de servidor?

Comment: lo realizo de forma loca

Comment: necesitas un servidor tipo XAMPP o WAMP en Windows para que interprete el PHP, ya que tu desarrollo en Muse es enteramente código HTML, CSS Y JS por lo cual no soporta código de backend

Comment: ok estoy realizando el mantenimiento en linux, existe alguna forma de validar eso alli?

Comment: necesitas instalar todo por separado, primero apache, luego php

Comment: ya todo esta instalado y configurado, e realizado varios desarrollos en este ambiente pero con este sistema me da ese error, hay que instalar alguna librería adicional o algo?